# XLSXWRITER changing color for individual column

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to change the fill color for a specific bar in a column chart that I'm designing through the spreadsheet using xlsxwriter. Here is a snippet from my code, below:

```
chartsheet=wb.add_chartsheet('ACCURACY')
chart=wb.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
chart.add_series({
'categories': '=SHEET1!$C$1:$O$1',
'values':     '=SHEET1!$C$15:$O$15',
'fill':   {'color': 'red'}
})
chartsheet.set_chart(chart)
```

This works but it sets all the bar fills to red, I just need the last bar would represents category at cell O1 and value at cell O15 to appear red.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that Excel does this is to treat each of the columns as a data *point* and apply a format to the point or none to have the series default.

You can do the same in XlsxWriter by using the [`points` series property](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_charts.html#chart-series-option-points) and just fill in formats for the columns as required, like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
]

worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])

chart.add_series({
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5',
    'points': [None, None, None, None, {'fill': {'color': 'red'}}],
})

worksheet.insert_chart('D3', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking. Thanks a bunch!